# C# Save email message as .msg file

Tags: c#, outlook, exchangewebservices

The following method saves an object of type `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage` on disk

```
private void SaveMailOnDisk(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage email, string pathLocation)
{
    FileStream fs = null;
    BinaryWriter sw = null;
    try
    {
        email.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
        MimeContent mc = email.MimeContent;
        fs = new FileStream(pathLocation, FileMode.Create);
        // mc.CharacterSet Is UTF8
        sw = new BinaryWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        sw.Write(mc.Content, 0, mc.Content.Length);
        sw.Flush();
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        sw?.Close();
        fs?.Close();
    }
}
```

The file is succesfully saved on disk but when I try to open it using `Outlook 2016` I receive the following error:

> We can't open path-to-msg-file. It's possible that the file is already open, or you don't have permissions to open it

Is there any way to save it on disk as `.msg` file. I mention that this method works for `.eml` files but I need `.msg` format.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that MIME format is not native to Exchange and you might lose MAPI-specific properties if you convert an Exchange item to the MIME (EML) format.

That being said, Outlook will be happy to open an EML file just as easily as an MSG file, so you are not gaining anything by converting EML to MSG.

If you want to preserve all MAP-specific properties, you would need to export using the Fast Transfer Stream format (FTS) - this is the format produced by the `ExportItems` EWS operation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/exportitems-operation and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange)

FTS format preserves all MAPI properties, but its internal structure is not documented. If you want to convert FTS data to an MSG file, you can do so using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author)  - create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object, call `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile` to create a new MSG file, call `RDOMail.Import(..., olFts)` to import the FTS data, then call `RDOMail.Save`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for `.msg` files using *EWS*. It's strictly just *Outlook* format.

This [3rd party library](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/downloadmessagetomsgfile.html) could satisfy your requirement however.

Regarding the error message you are getting, I would advise you to try updating your Outlook 2016 to the [latest update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484107/october-1-2019-update-for-outlook-2016-kb4484107).